# sklearn RandomForestClassifier runs out memory while building

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, random-forest

Is there any way to optimize memory usage so that it doesn't run out of memory during the classifier construction ?

I tried with `n_jobs = 2, 4` and `8`

input size `[500000,1000]` which I am loading with `mmap_memory = none`

here are the attributes that are set:

```
rf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=3,
                            criterion='entropy',
                            max_depth=20,
                            n_jobs=2,
                            warm_start=False,
                            class_weight=None)
```

other variables are on default

Comment: this doesn't seem too big. is the training data a sparse matrix? (if not try that)

Comment: The obvious thing is to try n_jobs=1 then. If not enough, lower the max_depth.

Comment: How much memory is it actually using? Is it running out because of what came before this call?

Comment: I tried it with n_jobs = 1, still runs out. I had to reduce my feature size and depth to manage it. RAM usage went from 2(when no other applications are using) to 7GB to 12GB before it crashed. (my ram limit is given as 15.6GB)

Comment: @maxymoo :it is kind of a sparse matrix actually. Do I have to explicitly cast a type ?